# Stop Python from using more than one cpu

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu-usage

I have a problem when I run a script with python. I haven't done any parallelization in python and don't call any mpi for running the script. I just execute "python myscript.py" and it should only use 1 cpu.

However, when I look at the results of the command "top", I see that python is using almost 390% of my cpus. I have a quad core, so 8 threads. I don't think that this is helping my script to run faster. So, I would like to understand why python is using more than one cpu, and stop it from doing so.

Interesting thing is when I run a second script, that one also takes up 390%. If I run a 3rd script, the cpu usage for each of them drops to 250%. I had a similar problem with matlab a while ago, and the way I solved it was to launch matlab with -singlecompthread, but I don't know what to do with python.

If it helps, I'm solving the Poisson equation (which is not parallelized at all) in my script.

---

UPDATE:
My friend ran the code on his own computer and it only takes 100% cpu. I don't use any BLAS, MKL or any other thing. I still don't know what the cause for 400% cpu usage is.
There's a piece of fortran algorithm from the library SLATEC, which solves the Ax=b system. That part I think is using a lot of cpu.

Comment: We could help more if we could see the code

Answer (score 2):

Your code might be calling some functions that uses C/C++/etc. underneath. In that case, it is possible for multiple thread usage.

Are you calling any libraries that are only python bindings to some more efficiently implemented functions?

Comment: Yes, my code calls C functions, but those C functions do not have any parallelization. I'm confused, why would those C functions use multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

You can always set your process affinity so it run on only one cpu. Use "taskset" command on linux, or process explorer on windows.

This way, you should be able to know if your script has same performance using one cpu or more.

Comment: Thanks, taskset worked perfectly. I will benchmark and see if running on serveral cpus helped or not.

Comment: I did run some tests and the performance is not comparable. If I run the code on 1 cpu, it takes ages for my code to run. This is rather strange.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your code uses SciPy or other numeric library for Python that is linked against Intel MKL or another vendor provided library that uses OpenMP? If the underlying C/C++ code is parallelised using OpenMP, you can limit it to a single thread by setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to 1:

`OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 python myscript.py`

Intel MKL for sure is parallel in many places (LAPACK, BLAS and FFT functions) if linked with the corresponding parallel driver (the default link behaviour) and by default starts as many compute threads as is the number of available CPU cores.

Comment: Thanjs for your suggestions. I'm looking into this in detail. I will get back to you again.